# Why is my Polymorphic Parent class calling the Subclass Method from within itself?

Tags: java, algorithm, inheritance, polymorphism, abstract-class

Heres the code I've made up so far.  Its fully functional and the only gripe I have with it is that my output for Weekly and Annual pay is always weekly...I'm at a loss as to how to get this from within either toString method.

```
public class PolyEmployees {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Employee [] myEmployees = {
            new Hourly("Joan Rivers", "Human Resources", 12.45, 34.3),
            new Hourly("Jason Nezbit", "Accounting", 15.25, 46.0),
            new Hourly("Ingrid Homes", "Secretary", 10.11, 38.7),
            new Salaried("Amy Liberman", "Human Resources Executive", 32.50),
            new Salaried("Xander Xavar", "Resource Processing", 29.20),
            new Salaried("Milly Rockhome", "PR Executive", 65.28)
        };

        // Output all employee types
        for (int i = 0; i < myEmployees.length; i++)    {
            System.out.println("\n" + myEmployees[i].toString());
        }                 
    }

}

/*
 * Employee abstract class
 */

abstract public class Employee {
    private String mName;
    private String mDepartment;
    protected Double mRate;

    // Constructor
    public Employee(String mName, String mDepartment, Double mRate) {
        this.mName = mName;
        this.mDepartment = mDepartment;
        this.mRate = mRate;
    }

    // Annual Pay
    public Double pay() {   // 40 Hours a Week, 52 weeks in a year
        return ((this.mRate * 40) * 52);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee: " + this.mName + "\nDepartment: " + this.mDepartment + "\nAnnual Pay: " + this.pay();
    }
}

/*
 * Hourly employee class
 */

public class Hourly extends Employee {
    private Double mHours;

    public Hourly(String mName, String mDepartment, Double mRate, Double mHours) {
        super(mName, mDepartment, mRate);
        this.mHours = mHours;
    }

    @Override
    public Double pay() {   // Weekly Pay, deals with overtime for hourly employee

        if (this.mHours > 40.0) {
            return ((40 * this.mRate) + ((this.mHours-40) * (this.mRate * 1.5)));
        }
        else    {
            return (this.mHours * this.mRate);
        }       
    }

    public String toString() {
        return super.toString() + "\tWeekly Pay: " + pay();
    }

}

/*
 * Salaried Employee Class
 */

public class Salaried extends Employee{

    public Salaried(String mName, String mDepartment, Double mRate) {
        super(mName, mDepartment, mRate);
    }

    @Override
    public Double pay() {   // Weekly Pay
        return (this.mRate * 40);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return super.toString() + "\tWeekly Pay: " + this.pay();
    }
}
```

I get all the output I want except for annual pay.  Stepping through the debugger it returns to the childs pay method even when calling from within the parent.  Since it's overridden I am not really surprised by this, but part of my deliverable is to get weekly from the subclass and annual from the super.

So that begs my question, how can I get Annual pay from the parent?  Do I have no choice but to cast it as an employee as part of my system output or is there something I am missing?

And on a side note, I love how fluid this site is.  Not many places I've been to show your post live as you type it.

NOTE ON COMMENT: According to my deliverables, both the salaried and hourly employees toString must return weekly pay.  The employee abstract class itself contains the method to return the annual pay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the option of calling the super from the subclass.  Your `toString` in `Salaried`, for example, could look like this:

```
return super.toString() + "\tWeekly Pay: " + this.pay()+ "\tAnnual Pay: " + super.pay());
```

Comment: Yep I feel silly for not thinking of that, this is the solution I was looking for, thank ya kindly :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, calling `pay()` in `Employee` will indeed call `Salaried.pay()` in the context of a `Salaried` object. That's the point of polymorphism - that derived classes can override behaviour.

Now it strikes me that your classes would be a lot clearer if you had separate methods for `getAnnualPay()` and `getWeeklyPay()` - possibly only having `getAnnualPay()` in the base class, and introducing `getWeeklyPay()` in `Salaried`.

Comment: Yes I agree it would be clearer.  Unfortuantely this is for a homework assignment, anytime I try to add more features my professor enjoys taking points away from me.  Business rules for the loose :(

Comment: So how much was actually specified? To me, the important thing is that you understand *why* the overridden pay method was being called, which appeared to surprise you.

Comment: Yes I understand it now, but initially I was surprised since I was calling pay from within the parent instead of the super.  I guess that part of overriding I didn't understand until just now.
Once someone posted super.pay as the way to get it from the parent, it sort of clicked.  I've already been calling the super class toString from the child so I feel sort of silly for not thinking of using the same calls to get the pay.

Answer (score 0):

In your subclasses, you're overriding the pay() method.  If you want the employees to have both an annual pay and a periodic pay, you should add abstract method periodicPay() for the subclasses to override and leave pay() as final.